# Making a Dictionary's key based on a for loop position

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary, c#-3.0

I am going to a directory picking up some files and then adding them to a Dictionary.

The first time in the loop the key needs to be A, second time B etc. Afer 26/Z the number represents different characters and from 33 it starts at lowercase a up to 49 which is lowercase q.

Without having a massive if statement to say if i == 1 then Key is 'A' etc etc how can I can keep this code tidy?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like you just need to keep an index of where you've got to, then some mapping function:

```
int index = 0;
foreach (...)
{
    ...
    string key = MapIndexToKey(index);
    dictionary[key] = value;
    index++;
}

...

// Keys as per comments
private static readonly List<string> Keys =
    "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopq"
    .Select(x => x.ToString())
    .ToList();

// This doesn't really need to be a separate method at the moment, but
// it means it's flexible for future expansion.
private static string MapIndexToKey(int index)
{
    return Keys[index];
}
```

EDIT: I've updated the `MapIndexToKey` method to make it simpler. It's not clear why you want a string key if you only ever use a single character though...

Another edit: I believe you could actually just use:

```
string key = ((char) (index + 'A')).ToString();
```

instead of having the mapping function at all, given your requirements, as the characters are contiguous in Unicode order from 'A'...

Comment: I get the gist of it but once I have the key I would then do myDicionary.Add(generateKey,myvalue);

Comment: @Jon: Why would you prefer `Add` over using the indexer?

Comment: One line of code?! I've just spotted the next problem 0-26 is uppercase, 26-32 is weird chars and 33-49 is lowercase but the char/int casting doesnt work

Comment: @Jon: It's one line of code whether you use the indexer or call `Add` directly though... Note that in my code I deliberately didn't attempt to handle values of 26 or higher, as you haven't specified what format you want the string in for that situation.

Comment: @Jon: What happens if it goes beyond 'z'?

Comment: Update question again! It goes from uppercase A-Z, 6 chars and then a-q

Comment: @Jon: I've updated my answer - but what if the index goes beyond q?

Comment: it wont my loop is always 0 -49

Comment: The reason I have a single character string is because I have a weird text file with a CSV and each letter represents a image. I read the file and output the image from my dictionary. I have Dictionary<string,bitmap>

Comment: @Jon: In that case, I think my answer does what you want now... although I think it would have done before anyway...

Comment: I've just seen your string key = ((char) (index + 'A')).ToString(); edit and I can confirm that does work!

Answer (score 1):

Keep incrementing from 101 to 132, ignoring missing sequence, and convert them to character. http://www.asciitable.com/

Use reminder (divide by 132) to identify second loop

Answer (score 1):

This gives you the opportunity to map letters to specific numbers, perhaps not alphabet ordered.

```
    var letters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
        .Select((chr, index) => new {character =  chr, index = index + 1 });

     foreach(var letter in letters)
     {
         int index = letter.index;
         char chr =  letter.character;
                // do something
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
for(int i=0; i<26; ++i)
{
    dict[(char)('A'+ (i % 26))] = GetValueFor(i);
}
```

Comment: Good attempt but my loop goes past 26